# 2019 Subaru Forester - Disable XM radio

Tags: subaru

I have no use for XM Radio. Any way to turn it off? Can it at least not make it the default radio source?

Comment: With such a new car, have you asked the dealer?

Comment: Further to Solar Mike's comment... While you're at the dealer, make sure that they didn't sell your name and address to the satellite radio companies. They don't tell you about that until you start getting the junk mail...

Comment: @PeteCon, Too late!  The minute the paperwork was entered into their system, his valuable information went into a database to be shared with all of the dealer's "business partners".